# Wordpress - Fetching all data and sorting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress. I have the following query to fetch data from database and it is working perfectly

```
$args1 = array(
 'post_type' => 'gallery',
 'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
 'post__in' => array(400, 403),
 'paged' => $paged,
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'ASC'                    

);

query_posts($args1);

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//And then some other code to display data
```

Using `'post__in' => array(400, 403),`in the above query I am fetching the rows where ID='400' AND '403' . So when I echo, I get to see only two information.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to fetch all data from the table but when I display the information I want to get the row where ID is 400 at first then 403 and then rest of the rows based on `'orderby' => 'title',` AND  'order' => 'ASC'

Could you please help with the query?

Thanks

### Edit

```
$args2 = array(
 'post_type' => 'gallery',
 'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
 'post__not_in' => array(400, 403),
 'paged' => $paged,
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'ASC'                    

);

query_posts($args2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work within the `query_post` argument, but it is supplementing valid SQL in to it.  Try:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'gallery',
 'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'orderby' => 'case when ID in (400,403) then -1 else title end, title',
 'order' => 'ASC'                    
);

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried your code.. it is giving me the first two result correctly (400,403) but after that it is not sorting the results based on title ASC .

Comment: Try adding `ASC` after `end` and see if that will help sort it? ^^

Comment: I just tried `'orderby' => 'case when ID in (400,403) then -1 else title end ASC, title',` but I found no change in the result :(

Comment: Does it order them by title correctly when `'orderby' => 'title',`?

Comment: Also, do you use a "Post Types Order" plugin or similar?

Comment: Yes, when I use `'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'` It works perfectly. I am going to check on that plugin. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. the "Post Types Order" plugin just solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help man :)

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to be possible using the Wordpress query structure like you are doing.  One possible solution is to do a second query looking for results not in (400, 403) and simply add this array of results to the end of your first array.

In order to do this, you should probably use `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()` so that it doesn't alter the main loop.

```
$array = get_posts($args1);
$array = array_merge($array, get_posts($args2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check the edited part of my question. Could you please tell me how to add these two array results?

Comment: @black_belt There are a number of ways. I have updated my answer with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try doing the following:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'gallery',
 'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'orderby' => 'ID = 400 DESC, ID = 403 DESC, title',
 'order' => 'ASC'                    
);

query_posts($args);
...
```

Let me know how this goes.

Comment: THanks a lot for your reply. I can see the first two posts correctly but then the rest of the rows do not appear in perfect order

Comment: If you use the exact arguments I posted, they should be sorted by title in ascending order (alphabetically). What are you getting instead of this?

Comment: I just replaced `id` with `ID` in your code. I am getting the first two results perfectly (at first 400 then 403) but rest of rows are showing up in random order. Like .. H,S,R,Z,H...

Comment: Another idea is to make the 400 and 403 sticky posts. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: No I didn't try that but I tried a query for `400 and 403` then echo the result and then another query for rest of the rows and then echo the result. But now I am trying to achieve the same result using only one query.